# How do you setup correctly an mvc3 intranet application with Medium trust on Windows 7 / IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, iis-7.5

I'm trying to deploy a default mvc3 intranet project with medium trust level on a locally installed IIS 7.5 on a Windows 7 premium SP1.

The app is using the defaultApplicationPool with an .net4 integrated pipeline.

I only changed one setting: in web.config I added the trust level="Medium" element.

Ran it in VS web express with the built-in aspnet dev. server. It works and I got the username properly displayed as expected.

I then used webdeploy, also with all the default settings to deploy it to my local IIS 7.5.
The first error I got is an access denied (401.2 unauthorized: logon failed due to server configuration).

However, if I remove the 'deny anonymous users' rule from the .net authorisation view, I get the home page but with an empty 'user' context.

I suspect this is caused by an IIS configuration setup but I don't know where to start troubleshooting this problem, assuming this kind of setup is even possible on my Win7 premium non-domain based machine.

So, If any IIS 7.5 expert could point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of Authentication mode are you running in; Forms or Windows? Check your web.config to see.  Is your site deployed to a server external to your network?

Comment: Windows authentication is used. The site is only deployed to my personal development machine via web deploy

Comment: I found the answer myself, it turns out it was a two-step solution in my case: 1)I removed the 'disallow anonymous users' rule in the net authorization section 2) I enabled basic authentication in the authentication-section. This last one has given me a lot of problems because the 'basic authentication' feature was not installed by default on my machine. Once I installed the feature, I could enable basic authentication for the web application and everything worked like a charm.

Comment: That's good - you should add your solution as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, it turns out it was a two-step solution in my case:

1)I removed the 'disallow anonymous users' rule in the net authorization section

2) I enabled basic authentication in the authentication-section. This last one has given me a lot of problems because the 'basic authentication' feature was not installed by default on my machine. Once I installed the feature, I could enable basic authentication for the web application and everything worked like a charm.